# RxJS Observables called in the reverse order

Tags: redux, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have the following code that dispatch 3 actions:

- deleteLineFailed
- showConfirmationMessage
- Wait 2s
- hideConfirmationMessage

For some reasons, the only way I was able to make it work is in the reverse order, what is it I'm doing wrong?

```
const deleteLineEpic = (action$, store) =>
action$.ofType(types.DELETE_LINE_REQUEST)
    .flatMap((action) => {
        return Observable.of(hideConfirmationMessage(action.line.productID))
                .delay(2000)
                .merge(
                    Observable.of(deleteLineFailure(action.line.productID)),
                    Observable.of(showConfirmationMessage(action.line.productID))
                );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following happens:

```
deleteLine        -----X------------
showConfirmation  -------Y----------
hideConfirmation  --------- 2s -----Z

merge             -----X-Y- 2s -----Z
```

All 3 streams get merged, and the one with the delay emits after two seconds while the other emit the action immediately.

So it might be better to do this:

```
const deleteLineEpic = (action$, store) =>
action$.ofType(types.DELETE_LINE_REQUEST)
    .flatMap((action) => {
        return Observable.merge(
            Observable.of(deleteLineFailure(action.line.productID),
            showConfirmationMessage(action.line.productID)),
            Observable.of(hideConfirmationMessage(action.line.productID))
                .delay(2000)
        )}
);
```

Here the actions in the first `Observable.of` get immediately emitted after each other, while hide actions is emitted later on.